# How to create unique code based on combination of two columns in python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create unique code based on combination of two columns.Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['ajay','AL'],['ajay','AB'],['ajay','AL'],['Alex','Ac'],['Alex','Ay'],['Alex','Ac'],['Alex','Ac'],['Bob','Ay'],['Clarke','cv']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Cat'],dtype=float)
```

Input :

```
    Name Cat
0    ajay  AL
1    ajay  AB
2    ajay  AL
3    Alex  Ac
4    Alex  Ay
5    Alex  Ac
6    Alex  Ac
7     Bob  Ay
8  Clarke  cv
```

output:

```
           Name Cat  code
0    ajay  AL  AJ_1
1    ajay  AB  AJ_2
2    ajay  AL  AJ_1
3    Alex  Ac  AL_1
4    Alex  Ay  AL_2
5    Alex  Ac  AL_1
6    Alex  Ac  AL_1
7     Bob  Ay  Bo_1
8  Clarke  cv  Cl_1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right, this script will create column `code`, where first two characters are from column `'Name'` and then number based on `'Cat'` column:

```
from itertools import count
from functools import lru_cache
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_num(n, c):
    return next(d[n])

df['code'] = df.apply(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(x['Name'][:2].upper(), get_num(x['Name'], x['Cat'])), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Name Cat  code
0    ajay  AL  AJ_1
1    ajay  AB  AJ_2
2    ajay  AL  AJ_1
3    Alex  Ac  AL_1
4    Alex  Ay  AL_2
5    Alex  Ac  AL_1
6    Alex  Ac  AL_1
7     Bob  Ay  BO_1
8  Clarke  cv  CL_1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create a column with a uuid like this:

```
import uuid    
df['code'] = df.apply(lambda x: uuid.uuid1(), axis=1)
```

or if you want to merge the two columns:

```
df['code'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Name + row.Cat, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my columns values are very large. basically column values are institute names  large interms of length

Comment: you could do row.Name[:3] to get the first 3 letter of the name and row.Cat[:3] to get the frist 3 letters of Cat column